# What does tinyint(3) mean in (SQLite) SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, tinyint

I realize that `tinyint` is a single byte integer (by the way, is it signed or unsigned?). What does the argument `(3)` signify? I've searched and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I'm using sqlite and I don't see any difference between `tinyint` and `tinyint(3)`.

Comment: @Mk12 It is because SQLite "mock implements" data-types (basically, it accepts the syntax but otherwise ignores it). Read the fine manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this blog page](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622163800/http://www.phpmag.ru/2009/02/15/mysql-tinyint1-and-tinyint4-which-one-is-bigger/) about MySQL column type definitions.

> For numeric types length modifier is actually display width, which has nothing to do with what can be stored in field. Yes, that’s it – both TINYINT(1) and TINYINT(4) can store values in range -128..127 (or for unsigned values 0..255), and are absolutely identical datatypes, with one small twist (which concerns date retrieval – see below).
>   Here is explanation of what is meant by display width, taken directly from the source:
>
> > The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column, nor the number of digits that are displayed for values having a width exceeding that specified for the column. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range allowed by three characters are displayed using more than three characters.

Comment: The question was about SQLite, but I realize that the OP added this precision after you answered. The other answer is more relevant now, not sure why this one is accepted.

Answer (score 8):

SQLite "mock implements" data-types on *columns*. Basically, it accepts the standard SQL syntax but otherwise ignores it. (But see type affinity and coercions.)

See [Manifest Typing](http://www.sqlite.org/different.html) in the "differences" documentation.

> Most SQL database engines use static typing. A datatype is associated with each column in a table and only values of that particular datatype are allowed to be stored in that column. SQLite relaxes this restriction by using manifest typing. **In manifest typing, the datatype is a property of the value itself, not of the column in which the value is stored.** SQLite thus allows the user to store any value of any datatype into any column regardless of the declared type of that column. (There are some exceptions to this rule: An INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column may only store integers. And **SQLite attempts to *coerce* values into the declared datatype of the column *when it can***.)

Also see [Datatypes in SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and Type Affinity:

> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the column, according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> - **If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.**
> - [other rules omitted for brevity]

---

For other databases, see the appropriate database-specific documentation :-)